# facebook blocked my json request

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, json, error-handling

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Doers Inc | The one who does something</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.query.results.json);
                    $.each(data.query.results.json.entries, function (i, v) {
                        $('#entries').append(data.query.results.json.entries[i].content + '<br />');
                     });
                 }, data: {
            q: 'select * from json where url="https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json"',
            format: "json"
                    }
           });
       });
   });


</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="entries"></div>
  </body>
</html>​
```

I used above code to fetch my facebook posts using json+jquery.but when i add the code to the html file in my site [here](http://doers.lk/post.html) .the output is showing

```
â€‹
```

sign.what is the problem for this code or any problem ?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you're wrapping FB API calls with Yahoo API? Facebook's API is perfectly accessible in client side JS as well...

Comment: we can't get the facebook feeds using direct getJSON called .so we have to use YQL

Comment: Everyone else manages to. Facebook's API supports JSONP as well; https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552?callback=foo

Comment: reason is probably that his server doesnt support CORS?

Comment: cross D is working without any problem..i used this code today morning my time and it worked and i made some changes into it.but now it's not working

Comment: it's working in the fiddle

Comment: you already have an answer, mark it;-) i was talking to @Matt

Answer (score 2):

Those characters are not coming from facebook, they are in your code. Which are breaking your javascript.

Here it is working after fixing the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/KubtF/

view-source:http://doers.lk/post.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Doers Inc | The one who does something</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.query.results.json);
            $.each(data.query.results.json.entries, function (i, v) {
                $('#entries').append(data.query.results.json.entries[i].content + '<br />');
            });
        }, data: {
            q: 'select * from json where url="https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json"',
            format: "json"
        }
    });
});
â€‹
â€‹  });
    </script>


    </head>
    <body>

<div id="entries"></div>â€‹



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: jsfiddle is working buddy http://www.doers.lk/post.html i removed unwanted signs but it's not going to work through

Comment: Copy the html from there and paste it into yours.

Comment: I can still see the characters in the source of the page. Remove them all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21383/discussion-between-charlieprynn-and-sami)

Answer (score 1):

You have some whitespace before the DOCTYPE-declaration, try to remove it.
Also, declare a charset for your page:

**UTF-8:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**ISO-8859-1:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```